# springbroot 404 when using multi-modei

Tags: spring-boot, rest, model, multi-table

I want set two  different tables.i have try this first model with corresponding service,controller and respository.Everythings is fine but when i use the same code with only changing the model,and develop a set of service,controller and respository.It cannot show what i expected.

my model:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTable;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(schema = "order")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    
    private int id;
    private String product_name;
    private int quantity;}
```

mycontroller:

```
package com.javatechie.trymysql.contoller;

import com.javatechie.trymysql.Entity.Order;

import com.javatechie.trymysql.service.OrderService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class OrderController {
    @Autowired
    private OrderService service;

    @PostMapping("/add/orders")
    public List<Order> addOrders(@RequestBody List<Order> orders){
        return  service.saveOrders(orders);
    }
}
```

service:

```
package com.javatechie.trymysql.service;

import com.javatechie.trymysql.Entity.Order;
import com.javatechie.trymysql.repository.OrderRepository;
import com.javatechie.trymysql.repository.ProductRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class OrderService {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository Repository;


    public List<Order> saveOrders(List<Order> order) {
        return Repository.saveAll(order);
    }
}
```

repository:

```
package com.javatechie.trymysql.repository;
import com.javatechie.trymysql.Entity.Order;
import com.javatechie.trymysql.Entity.Product;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order,Integer> {

}
```

my ide pattern is like:

```
 com.javatechie.trymysql
    -entity
    --Product
    --Order
    
    -controller
    --productcontroller
    --ordercontroller
    
    -service
    --productservice
    --orderservice
    
    -repository
    --productrespository
    --orderreposiory
    
    -productconfig

    -Trymysqlapplication
```

Postman request:

```
  [{
   
"proudct_name":"sand",
"quantity":5

},{
       
       "product_name":"fruit",     
       "quantity":2
}]
```

error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-10-17T13:14:03.284+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/add/orders"
}
```

Everytime i run the server it display the following log:

```
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_1_0_, product0_.name as name2_1_0_, product0_.price as price3_1_0_, product0_.quantity as quantity4_1_0_ from product_tbl product0_ where product0_.id=?
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_1_0_, product0_.name as name2_1_0_, product0_.price as price3_1_0_, product0_.quantity as quantity4_1_0_ from product_tbl product0_ where product0_.id=?
```

But it still  works fine

later i add the second table it just show me:
Hibernate: select order0_.id as id1_0_0_, order0_.product_name as product_2_0_0_, order0_.quantity as quantity3_0_0_ from order order0_ where order0_.id=?
2022-10-17 21:21:11.916  WARN 3828 --- [nio-9191-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000

i dont why my log file automatically generate this sql and got the error when it is not the model "product"?
I dont know which step i have done wrong when trying using the second model(order)

Comment: So you have, save order works but not the save product? Can you provide your service layer? Also product entity and its setup?

Comment: Thanks for your reply .i have edit the service layer.i have save order is not work but the product work.They have the same template and only difference in content .Do  there some required code when treating multi-table?

Comment: What is the error? What happens when you send this JSOn in Postman? If it is just a 404, I guess the error is the URL in Postman.

Comment: it is 500 with internal server error

Comment: Please check the server error logs and provide the error you get.

Comment: It shows that:    {Hibernate: select order0_.id as id1_0_0_, order0_.product_name as product_2_0_0_, order0_.quantity as quantity3_0_0_ from order order0_ where order0_.id=?).It seems that the my command line automatically set to this query but i have no idea on it

Comment: This is a select query and you are inserting data so the query is irrelevant. Please check and find out the error/exception you get.

Comment: It said my error is sql syntax error :   ERROR 3828 --- [nio-9191-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order order0_ where order0_.id=1' at line 1.But i should havent wriiten this query

Comment: I have find why my error .the table cannot set as "order" since it is reserved in sql and i set the table name to "orders",everything works fine.Thank you for all of the responses

Answer (score 0):

Extracted details from comments.

As you have table name `order` which is a reserved keyword in MySQL. So you have to change the table name to another name that is not a reserved keyword. Change to `orders` resolves the issue.